# Exception Logging with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsf, exception, logging

I have heard that it is possible to log (or do something else) Exceptions with Spring in my web-App, so I don't have to manually insert in every "catch(){}" block the Log-function.

Does anyone have experience with Spring-overall-logging? I just want to get informed when an error appears

Comment: spring mvc internally uses jsp right and you have exception handling there both declaritively and programatically. just use the declerative exception handling in your web.xml for your spring app that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

ExceptionHandler is the central point for handling unexpected Exceptions that are thrown during the Faces lifecycle. The ExceptionHandler must not be notified of any Exceptions that occur during application startup or shutdown.

See the specification prose document for the requirements for the default implementation. Exceptions may be passed to the ExceptionHandler in one of two ways:

1.)By ensuring that Exceptions are not caught, or are caught and re-thrown.

This approach allows the ExceptionHandler facility specified in section JSF.6.2 to operate on the Exception.

2.)By using the system event facility to publish an ExceptionQueuedEvent that wraps the Exception.

This approach requires manually publishing the ExceptionQueuedEvent, but allows more information about the Exception to be stored in the event. The following code is an example of how to do this.

**Global Exception Handler** – Exception Handling is a cross-cutting concern, it should be done for all the pointcuts in our application. We have already looked into Spring AOP and that’s why Spring provides @ControllerAdvice annotation that we can use with any class to define our global exception handler.

The handler methods in Global Controller Advice is same as Controller based exception handler methods and used when controller class is not able to handle the exception.

**Sample Code**

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView getExceptionPage(Exception e, HttpServletRequest request) {
            request.setAttribute("errorMessageObject", e.toString());
            return model; 
    }
```

** Here we can catch the base exception class `Exception.class` or any other exception class. Also we can throw and catch our own custom defines exception class.

Comment: is it possible to "equip" my application with a global exception handler? I dont have any controllers or other spring components; I just want a kind of a global exception handling (to log all errors (caught or uncaught))?

Comment: might be interested in this link
http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc